# Characterization of the sequence $x_1=\cos(x), x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n)$ where $x>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

> Let $x>0$, $x_1=\cos(x),$ and $x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n), \forall n\geq1.$ Then the sequence  $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is
>
> 1. bounded but not monotone,
> 2. bounded but not Cauchy,
> 3. Cauchy,
> 4. convergent.

It is a multiple select question , so it may have more than one correct option.

The above sequence is bounded, it's trivial. Also if the sequence converges then it will converge to a real root $\ \ l\ $ of $\ \ \ l-\cos(l)=0$.

I tried by taking a particular value of $x$. Suppose $x=\pi/2$, then the sequence will become $\{0,1,\cos(1),\cos(\cos(1)),\cos(\cos(\cos(1))),.....\}$. Without using calculator, I think we can't say whether this sequence is monotone or not.

Again while showing 'Cauchy' I considered $|x_m-x_n|\leq |x_{m-1}-x_{n-1}|\leq|x_{m-2}-x_{n-2}|\leq...$

I don't know how can we show whether the sequence Cauchy or not from the above relation.

> Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: On a figure, try to represent $\cos(x)$ and $f(x)=x$ and use them to graphically represent what happens. It will not be a formal proof but help you understanding what to prove

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number

Comment: "Without using a calculator..." I strongly advise you to *use* a calculator as a tool of discovery. What you learn might be surprising and insightful in regards to formulating a strategy to answer your questions rigorously.

Answer (score 4):

Hint 1. Note that if $0\leq x_n\leq 1$, and $x_n\leq x_{n+1}=\cos(x_n)$ then $x_n\in[0,a]$ and $x_{n+1}\in [a,1]$ where $a\simeq 0.73908$ is [the unique solution of the equation $\cos(x)=x$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html) . Therefore 
$$x_{n+2}=\cos(x_{n+1})\leq x_{n+1}.$$
So the sequence has an alternating behaviour.

Hint2. If you show that the function $x\to \cos(\cos x)$ is strictly increasing in $[0,1]$ then it follows that the subsequences  $\{x_{2n}\}_n$ and $\{x_{2n+1}\}_n$ are strictly monotone and bounded. What may we conclude?

P.S. You may also note that $x\to \cos(\cos x)$ is a contraction in $[0,1]$ and [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://Banach%20fixed-point%20theorem) can be applied.

Answer (score -1):

There's only one real root $y$ such that $\cos y=y$ (it's about $0.74$).  In the neighborhood of $y$,
$$
x_n=y+\varepsilon\implies x_{n+1}=\cos(y+\varepsilon)=\cos y - \varepsilon \sin y + O(\varepsilon^2)=y-\varepsilon\sqrt{1-y^2}+O(\varepsilon^2)...
$$
since $\vert{\sin y} \vert< 1$, this leads to exponential (and non-monotonic) convergence to $y$ if $x_n$ ever lands close enough to it.  So it seems like you'll sometimes have 1., 3., and 4. all true.  However, it's not obvious without further analysis that 3. and 4. *have* to hold... it might be that you can converge to some other stable limit cycle, or even if there were an unstable cycle, you might stay on it for some initial conditions.  (Update: per other answers, in this case there are no other limit cycles and the fixed point is universally attracting.)

Comment: Actually, you may not.